Cache HDFS table in Apache Flink
I need to read and cache parquet table in HDFS (this table is updated once a day in another Spark job). I want to cache it so that I can join it later with my Kafka topic (this topic is read in stream mode). In Spark it's done really easily with just one command .cache(), but I can't find any simple solution in Flink. Maybe I'm missing something?
I'm new to Flink and would greatly appreciate your help!

If you're using the DataStream API, then you would create a FileSource for the Parquet files, with some monitoring interval (so that when the table is updated, you get new stream records). Then you would do a stateful join with a KeyedProcessFunction, where you save the records from this stream in state.
With the Table API it would be simpler to implement.
